# Having an issue with a return value in combination with a completion handler

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, return, completionhandler

I created the setAvatarImage function to download an UIImage which is then getting returned in a default collection view function. I can see in the console that the UIImage is getting downloaded, thus the return value should be the UIImage. However no image is displayed in the collection view.

```
func setAvatarImages(_ senderUid: String!, completionhandler: @escaping (UIImage!) -> Void) {

    let ref = DatabaseReference.users(uid: senderUid).reference()
    ref.observe(.value, with:  { (snapshot) in
        let user = User(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        user.downloadProfilePicture(completion: { (image, error) in
            if image != nil {
                let profileImage = image
                print(profileImage!)
                completionhandler(profileImage!)
            } else if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
        })
    })
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    var avatarImage: JSQMessagesAvatarImage!
    setAvatarImages(message.senderUID) { (profileImage) in
        avatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: profileImage, diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
        print(avatarImage)
    }
    return avatarImage
}
```

I think there is a problem with the asynchronous return function. But I thought, that giving the setAvatarImage function a completionhandler should solve that problem. 
Can anyone give me some advise, so that the downloaded Image is returned!!

EDIT !!!

Taking Alex suggestions into account I changed the setAvatarImage function.
First I Created an dictionary:

```
   var profileImages = [String : UIImage]()
```

The intention was to get all images into profileImages with the user.uid as the key within the viewdidLoad.

```
func setAvatarImages() {

    for user in chat.users {
        print(user.fullName)
        user.downloadProfilePicture(completion: { (image, error) in
            print(image!)
            if let profileImage = image {
                self.profileImages[user.uid] = profileImage
            } else if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

SetAvatarImages gets called in the viewDidLoad.

To return the AvatarImage in the default function from the JSQMessagesViewController I did that:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    let avatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: profileImages[message.senderUID], diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
    return avatarImage
}
```

The cool thing was that it did work, for a few tries. But suddenly it crashes when downloading the image in the user.downloadProfileImage function. The only thing I changed before it started to crash everytime was that I deleted the breaking points in the console to see how fast it works ... Does anyone has an idea why it crashes now.
And yeah I know that it is better to add some Caching for the images, but first this issue has to be solved!

Comment: I am not personally using JSQMessages but when you look at their project on Github it seems like the syntax is different so you may want to take a look there :). Also for your image variable I would suggest you not to capitalize it because capitalized names are generally for class and struct names and it might be confusing when someone reads your code

Comment: Yeah I had a look, but logic wise I cannot see a downside in the method I used compared to their code. The downloadProfilePicture function works pretty well for the rest of the app to download pictures rocket fast. But thanks for your response, I will have a look again in the sample project

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed, did you try to put the return avatarImage inside your setAvatarImages completion block ? Because since your completion block is called asynchronously, chances are the line "return avatarImage" will be called before your completion block is even called. And that might be the issue here

Comment: Hmm, I tried a lot of things, but I think, it is not possible to return something with a return command insight an completion block, because a completion block cannot handle it. At least thats what I experienced.

Comment: Yes actually you would likely get a Missing return in a function expected to return 'JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource' .. Well again I am not sure how JSQMessages works, but you could try to put your  setAvatarImages(message.senderUID) method in the viewDidLoad, and in when you get your profileImage you set it using  JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage() and then you reload your data, which will cause your data source method to be be run again

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

I just had to add a completionhandler to the setAvatarImages function!

```
 func setAvatarImages(completion: @escaping ([String : UIImage]) -> Void) {

    for user in chat.users {
        print(user.fullName)
        user.downloadProfilePicture(completion: { (image, error) in
            print(image!)
            if let profileImage = image {
                self.profileImages[user.uid] = profileImage
                completion(self.profileImages)
            } else if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and then in viewDidLoad

```
setAvatarImages(completion: { (profileUserImages) in
        print(profileUserImages)
    })
```

Next stop caching!